# Looking for a GMail-like autosuggest textbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I need an auto-suggest textbox, just like the one for entering the recipient's email address in GMail when we compose an email.

Answer (score 5):

[JQueryUI does this.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) You'll want a combination of the Custom data and Multiple values options.

Answer (score 1):

See this document:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

This uses ajax query which would be easy to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah..U can Use AJAXSCRIPT Manager and AjaxAutoExtender

Put your coding in Autoextender method to retrive datas from SQL-server

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/).

It will automatically validate the values as gmail does. And you can enter multiple values and you can remove values by clicking on close button of the entry
If you want simple autocomplete then you can go with this [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).